# Angular material Snackbar: not overwriting previous message with new message

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I am using a Snackbar to display error and warning messages to the user. Sometimes these can happen close to each other in time, closer than the display duration time of the first message. So close that it does not give enough time to the user to read the first message before overwriting with the second message.

Is there a way of changing the behaviour to waiting for the end of the first message before displaying the second, or piling them up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of invoking the Snackbar for each message, you could put all of them into an array to mimic a 'queue' of messages. I would suggest having a service which is responsible for handling this.

Then, in this service you can subscribe to the Snackbar's `afterDismissed()` callback which will fire whenever the Snackbar closes. Here's a simple example of what that would look like:

```
messageQueue: string[] = [
'Message 1',
'Message 2',
'Message 3'
]

private displaySnackbar(): void {
  const nextMessage = this.getNextMessage();

  if(!nextMessage){
    return;
  }

  this.snackBar.open(nextMessage, undefined, { duration: 1000 })
  .afterDismissed()
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.displaySnackbar();
  });
}

private getNextMessage(): string | undefined {
  return this.messageQueue.length ? this.messageQueue.shift() : undefined;
}
```

EDIT:

So as to avoid any confusion, in the example I have provided I do not recommend calling `displaySnackbar()` directly (hence the `private` visibility scope). Instead, here's how I have exposed it (as you can see in the Stackblitz demo from below):

```
addMessage(message: string): void {
  this.messageQueue.push(message);

  if(!this.processingMessage) {
    this.displaySnackbar();
  }
}
```

This just depends on the `processingMessage` flag to determine whether or not it should invoke the `displaySnackbar()` method. Of course we will also need to set this flag so here's the updated `displaySnackbar()`:

```
private displaySnackbar(): void {
  const nextMessage = this.getNextMessage();

  if(!nextMessage){
    this.processingMessage = false; // No message in the queue, set flag false
    return;
  }

  this.processingMessage = true; // A message was dequeued and is being processed

  this.snackBar.open(nextMessage, undefined, { duration: 1000 })
  .afterDismissed()
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.displaySnackbar();
  });
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wuw3qh) is the basic, working Stackblitz demo.

In the demo, you will see that you can 'spam click' the 'Add Message' button which will queue up all of the messages that get created, but the Snackbar will only display them once each message has finished being displayed for 1 second.

Comment: Thanks for the working example, I am indeed thinking of bagging all of this in its own service as I foresee reusing in a future project. Many thanks again.

Comment: Does this actually work? when do you start triggering the notification the first time? aren't you re-initialising a subscription every time? there's no way this, in this configuration, works properly in production.

Comment: Yes it does work, the Stackblitz example in the post should show that. The `afterDismissed` subscription is to a one-shot observable (similar to a http `get`) so there are no subscriptions left behind after the fact. How is it that "there is no way this, in this configuration, works..." exactly?