# Delay from last emission in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I have a source `Observable` with error messages, and I want to display a snackbar for every one of them. The snackbar appears for `DELAY` ms, then disappears.

The source might spam values, therefore the next message should wait until `DELAY` ms pass since the last message appeared. If this is the first message or `DELAY` ms already passed since last message, the message should display immediately ([example source-result timings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKO4D.png)).

I couldn't work out the correct operator combination for this.

Comment: Are you using Angular Material's SnackBar?

Comment: Yes, I am using Material snackbar

Comment: I ended up using https://stackoverflow.com/a/55453545/15914746, however a clean rxjs solution would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Angular Material's Snackbar, you can use a helpful method `.afterDismissed()` which returns an observable that emits when the snackbar is closed.

```
private emitError = new Subject<string>();
private snackBar$: Observable<string>;

constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
  this.snackBar$ = this.emitError
  .pipe(
    concatMap(message => this.getSnackBarDelay(message)),
    tap(message => this._snackBar.open(message, 'OK', { duration: 5000 }))
  );
}

public openSnackBar(message: string) {
  this.emitError.next(message);
}

private getSnackBarDelay(message: string) {
  const snackbarRef = this._snackBar._openedSnackBarRef;
  if (!!snackbarRef) {
    return snackbarRef!.afterDismissed().pipe(mapTo(message));
  } else {
    return of(message);
  }
}
```

Here's the step-by-step process of what's happening.

1. Our subject emits a new error message.
2. Our observable pipes into the subject and receives the message string.
3. Before we use the snackbar, we invoke a method that returns an inner observable. (We use `concatMap()` so it creates an ordered queue)
4. This method creates a reference variable of our snackbar.
5. If the snackbar is open, return an observable that emits the message once it is closed.
6. If the snackbar isn't open, return an observable that immediately emits the message.
7. Back to our `snackBar$` observable, it receives the message (either immediately, or after snackbar is closed) and triggers the snackbar.

The added benefit to this, is that you're not trying to synchronize timers with when the snackbar should close. Even if the user clicks to dismiss the snackbar early, it will immediately trigger the next queued error.

Here's the Stackblitz of a working prototype: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwwcqb?file=src/app/snack-bar-component-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that `source$` is the Observable which emits the error messages.

You can transform `source$` into a new Observable which satisfies your requirements like this. Comments are inline.

```
source$.pipe(
  // concatMap ensures that the notifications produced by the Observable
  // returned by the function passed as parameter are concatenated one after the other
  concatMap(i => {
    // the function 'of' transforms each notification of source$ into a new Observable which notifies
    // only once and then complete
    return of(i).pipe(
      // this tap simulates the fact that you open the Snackbar
      tap(msg => console.log('Open Snackbar for message', msg)),
      // introduce a delay between open and close
      delay(DELAY),
      // this tap simulates the fact that you close the Snackbar
      tap(msg => console.log('CLOSE Snackbar for message', msg)),
      // introduce a delay before the next error message is shown on the Snackbar
      // this delay represents the minimum delay, i.e. if the source$ does notify 
      // the next message only after this delay, this delay will have no effect
      delay(DELAY),
    )
  })
).subscribe()
```

[This stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-eptk7j?file=index.ts) simulates your case, at least as far as I understand it.